# How to persuade PowerPoint to reasonable behaviour while importing images

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2003

I create a PPT presentation with lots of images. When I copy the image into the slide, the image is 5x times bigger than then slide, overflowing the visible frame of course... Making it smaller takes a lot of work with mouse (resizing, dragging etc.). Doing this with 100+ photos is pretty annoying.

How to persuade PowerPoint (I use PPT 2003) to behave reasonably by default? How to make this process as comfortable as possible? I would like to have all the images zoomed exactly to the slide.

Comment: Do you need to do that with only powerpoint or can you use a third program?

E.g. use one of the many [image resizer](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/image-resizer-powertoy-clone-for-windows-7vista/) programs to whittle all images down to your desired resolution, and then import them.

Comment: @Hennes, this is a workaround that leads me to interesting idea - just change the DPI of the image to that of the presentation! Would you know where can I get/set the DPI resolution of the presentation?

Comment: Wouldn't that lead to the full sized image being loaded and run-time scaled down in ppt?  (Thus with an unnecessary large .ppt file and all the disadvantages of that size (big, slow loading, using much memory, ...)) ?

Comment: Well, the size could be also tuned.. @Hennes, so do you know where can I get/set the dimensions, dpi, etc. of the slide? So that I know how to resize the images. And also, is there any function to create multiple slides from multiple images automatically?

Comment: Nope. I have successfully avoided using ppt for most of my life. I know roughly what it can do and I know how people abuse it (e.g. way to much text on the screen, too small fonts, animated stuff where it is not needed and only distracts. Putting everything on a sheet and just reading from it...granted, neither of those are the fault of powerpoint.  From a support perspective I learned that there is a somewhat hidden menu option to scale down  images to print or presentation size (which reduced some 50MB ppt files to 3MB, allowing them to be e-mailed).  But that is the sum of my ppt knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fairly easy (note that the english words might be slightly different; I am trying to translate it back to english from Czech PowerPoint. Damned localizations, hate 'em):

- Menu: Insert -> Picture -> New photoalbum -> File or diskette
- choose all the pictures you want to add and confirm
- make sure that layout is set to "resize to slide"
- click create

Fairly easy and exactly what I needed!! No need to resize images manually etc.!

Answer (score -1):

You can resize an individual photo easily with many programs, such as IrfanView (a favorite of mine), or you can make shrunk versions of a whole folder full of files in one swell foop by using EasyThumbnails.  It's intended for making thumbnails, but you can adjust the output size to whatever you want, so it should work fine for this.  It's freeware:
http://www.fookes.com/ezthumbs/

Comment: That's not what I asked - I know how to work with images. I want to know how to harmonize them with PowerPoint. See my discussion with Hennes.